# How to make a your page not scrollable but a div is scrollable

Tags: css, scroll, sidebar

I am making a game with sidebar where you can get upgrades the pages scroll is disabled but I want it so when I reach enough upgrades in the sidebar you can scroll down to see the ones that exceed the page.

Any help is appreciated check out the game at https://clickersandbeyond.com
Code below

```html
        <div class="btn-holder" id="btnHolder">
            <button class="button" id="gas87" onclick="gas87()">Gas <br><strong>87</strong>(300 Clicks gives 1 autoclicks)</button>
            <button class="button" id="gas89" onclick="gas89()">Gas <br><strong>89</strong>(1,000 Clicks gives 5 autoclicks)</button>
            <button class="buttonSpecial" id="engine" onclick="V6Engine()">Upgrade engine to <strong>V6</strong>(5,000 Clicks allows you to have up to 400 autoclicks and also gives you 2 CpCs)</button>
            <button class="button" id="cylinders" onclick="cylinders()">Quote unquote "Large Cylinders" (10,000 Clicks gives 60 autoclicks)</button>
            <button class="button" id="nitro" onclick="nitro()">Nitro pack (60,000 Clicks gives 400 autoclicks)</button>
            <button class="buttonReqD" id="holeInHood" onclick="cutAHole()">Saw a "crude" hole in your hood (100,000 Clicks, puts a large, crude, hole in your hood so you can manage to fit a V8 engine in. Required to get V8)</button>
            <button class="buttonSpecial" id="V8engine" onclick="V8Engine()">Upgrade engine to <strong>V8</strong> (1,000,000 Clicks allows you to have up to 1,500 autoclicks and also gives you 4 CpCs)</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you solve your problem without posting any code? See [mcve]

Comment: There is too much code to add

Comment: **minimal** reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow-y: auto;` or `scroll` in the sidebar container.

For example:

```
#btnHolder {
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

When the content exceeds 200px, it will show a scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out.